# fullscreen stuck after xcode debug crash and restart limited to user

Tags: xcode, macos, fullscreen

While developing fullscreen app in xcode, system froze after launch. restarted system, logged in as previous user and nothing happened. stuck on "shield window" with no possible keyboard input. used ssh in from another machine, found nothing in process list I could kill to change the result. Suspect that error spawned from getting and outputting "CGShieldingWindowLevel".
Have run the gamut of disk-utils to no avail. Eight hours so far. Please help, many thanks.

osx 10.4.1, xcode 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you developed an application that replaces the login screen or automatically runs when you login via the GUI?

If it runs from the GUI - an SSH session should let you either edit your user settings or rename/move the application so it won't run the next time.

I've been working on a fullscreen app for a Mac MINI - I connect via SSH and have the application exit (tell application "X" to QUIT), grab latest source from SVN, have XCode compile from the command line, copy the app to the correct location, then have finder launch the new app.